# how can I add attribute to field label in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a solution that I add form fields in the template individually like {{form.title}}, {{form.summary}}, and so on, and then hardcoding the label in the template. is there any better way to add attributes to field labels using Django and actually I don't know the cons of my current solution

Comment: You can add attributes to fieldtypes of form in form classes directly.

Comment: I need to add attributes to the label not the input field, if this what you mean then please tell me how. thank you